# Update page content via ssh rather than web interface

Tags: templates, server, content, workflow, template-manager

Im attempting to update page content (template content more specifically) in vim over ssh and have experienced trouble with the changes being committed.

### For example:

I have a common footer template where I am changing some information. Through ssh, I navigate to the file, open in vim, and write the changes. *everything is ok to this point*

I go to the website and the change **has not** been committed… even with hard refresh.

Then, if I navigate to the same footer file in the web interface, the change still isn't present. If I go ahead and make the change there, as you would imagine, it works just fine.

### So my question is:

Is there some cache setting or configuration option that makes editing the template files directly on the server as functional as committing changes through the gui?

Answer (score 1):

1) Verify the template files system path is correct:

Design > Templates > Global Preferences

2) Generally speaking, you can clear the current cache by navigating to "Tools > Data > Clear Caching". You can also try deleting all of the cache files in the /system/expressionengine/cache/ folder but I haven't tried that for this type of scenario.

Comment: Does the issue sound like a cache problem? I was just making a guess because I couldnt come up with a better explanation. Im not entirely sure if EE is even setup to be edited that way, or furthermore, if it **can** be setup for that type of workflow.

Comment: It sounds like a caching issue to me. That is, I think the cache is cleared automatically when you save a template via the backend. Check to see if you have Template Caching enabled on any of your templates (or via your Templates' Global Preferences).